# Deleting elements in array, index out of bounds (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a simple script in Matlab where I compare adjacent element and delete one of them if there difference between them is one.

```
for i=1:length(Vector) - 1
if Vector(i+1) - Vector(i) == 1
    Vector(i) = [];
end
 if i == length(Vector) 
    break
 end
```

end

However, I'm getting an error that my indices are out of bound. I am not sure why, my algorithm seems to me should work. Is there perhaps a simpler way to do this with internal functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
Vector(i) = []
```

you are changing the size of your array and that will produce first a result you are not looking for and second the if condition that follows in the code does not prevent the script to go out of bounds. One way to solve this could be using an auxilary vector.

```
Vector = [1,5,6,3,5,7,8,9];
tmp = [];
j = 1;

for i=1:length(Vector)-1
    if Vector(i+1) - Vector(i) == 1
        continue
    end
    tmp(j) = Vector(i);
    j = j + 1;
end

tmp(end+1) = Vector(end);
Vector = tmp
```

Note that I am supposing that you always want to keep the last element.

If you want to avoid for loops you could also do:

```
Vector = [1,5,6,3,5,7,8,9];
tmp = circshift(Vector, [0,-1]); %shifted version of Vector
tmp(end) = Vector(end)+2; %To ensure that the last element will be included
index = tmp-Vector ~= 1; %indices that satisfy the condition
Vector = Vector(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

pabaldenedo is correct that the problem is removing elements in the middle of iteration.

A better solution is simply to vectorize the search and removal:

```
mask = [diff(Vector) == 1, 0]; % find elements where the step is 1
Vector = Vector(~mask);        % exclude them
```

This should also be a lot faster.

If repeated elements should be removed when they are one greater than the prior element, you can repeat that.  Unfortunately MATLAB has no do-while loop.

```
mask = [diff(Vector) == 1, 0]; % find elements where the step is 1
while any(mask)                % if we found elements to exclude
    Vector = Vector(~mask);        % exclude them
    mask = [diff(Vector) == 1, 0]; % search again
end
```

Comment: Why do you have to include the zero in the vector in the first line? mask = [diff(Vector) == 1, 0]

Answer (score 0):

I think this

> if Vector(i+1) - Vector(i) == 1

could be the problem when you have a vector of size 1 the index i+1 does not exists

Comment: I think you're right. Maybe there is a better way of doing this by not comparing elements in this manner